# Is there an alternative People API functionality for Contacts API that searches contacts and returns approximately 100 contacts?

Tags: google-contacts-api, google-people-api

People API has a method (searchContacts) which caters to searching contacts. However, it's only capped at 10 results/contacts returned. I would like to know if there is another alternative method or functionality that would search and return more or less 100 results.

Answer (score 0):

#### Unfortunately, what you want cannot be achieved.

However, what you *can* do in this situation is to file a feature request on Google's Issue Tracker [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=344199&template=1040408&pli=1) and provide all the needed details.